# How to create dynamic dependent dropdown list in Google Sheets using Named Ranges

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way in Google Sheets (either with **or** without Google Apps Script) to create a dynamic dependent dropdown list using defined Named Ranges as the dropdown values for the dependent column?

What I'm trying to achieve is the following in the **"Details" Sheet** — a dependent dropdown in Column J starting Row 7, which depends on the value selected in Column I:

- If "**Common Fruits**" is selected in **Column I**, then the same row in **Column J** will have a dropdown list that pulls values from the Named Range "**subcat_common**".
- If "**Tropical Fruits**" is selected in **Column I**, then the same row in **Column J** will have a dropdown list that pulls values from the Named Range "**subcat_tropical**".
- If "**Exotic Fruits**" is selected in **Column I**, then the same row in **Column J** will have a dropdown list that pulls values from the Named Range "**subcat_exotic**".

["Details" Sheet that should contain the dependent dropdown in Column J starting Row 7, which is dependent on the value selected in Column I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Txa6.png)

The subcategory **Named Ranges** are located in a second sheet (the **"Summary" Sheet**), where all the subcategories (Named Ranges) are in a single Column H.  (Unfortunately, the project requires that the lists of subcategories for the dependent dropdown must all be in the same column and not in separate columns.)

["Summary" Sheet containing all the subcategories in a single Column H, where each list of subcategories has its own Named Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgjl8.png)

**Additional Requirements:**

- In all dropdown menus, both the category names and subcategory names must be able to show any spaces and symbols in their names (i.e., names that have 2 or more words cannot be combined into 1 word by deleting the space(s) or by using an underscore).
- Whatever method is used to create this dependent dropdown in Column J must allow all the dropdowns in this "Details" Sheet to maintain their integrity even when the data in this sheet is filtered/sorted and even when the user adds or deletes rows in this sheet.
- The dependent dropdown must pull from a list of Named Ranges in order for the subcategory values to remain dynamic (so that the user can change the subcategory names and add/delete rows in the subcategory lists in the "Summary" Sheet as they wish, with all of these changes instantly and dynamically reflected in the dependent dropdown in the "Details" Sheet).
- The different subcategory Named Ranges in the "Summary" Sheet must all be in the same column.
- The dependent dropdown list must ignore any blanks in the Named Ranges.
- The dependent dropdown list must reject any invalid input (any input that differs from the dropdown values).

I tried to enter different custom IF formulas into Data Validation in Google Sheets to achieve the described dependent dropdown effect, but it didn't work in Google Sheets (even though it worked in Excel).

Any help is appreciated!